# Check if user already exists in mongodb and passport

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I'm new to passport and I'm trying to create a "register" page. This actually works fine, and the log-in form as well. However, I want to check if the username entered already exists, and if it does, throw an error to the user. Here is my code so far:

```
expressApp.post("/register", function(request, response){

User.findOne({username: request.body.username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        if (user) {

        }
     else {

    User.register(new User({
        username: request.body.username,
        type: "Student"}),
        request.body.password, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(request, response, function(){
            response.redirect("/");
        });
    });
 }
    })
});
```

However, If someone chooses a username that already exists, then i want to be able to tell them that there is an error.

Comment: Before registering the user, first find the person in the database. If they exist, return error from there, and in the 'else' block of the 'find' function, call the above registration code.

Comment: I've edited my post. Would it be something like this? And do you know what I would need to display a simple error message if the user excists?

Comment: If you use mongoose Schema, this can help you in some other ways, `username:{type:String, unique:true}`, and then you can send request for direct registering without a find query, if err, simply you can send a message with User exist, if success- send your success message

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this.

```
expressApp.post("/register", function(request, response) {

  User.findOne({
    username: request.body.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return err
    } else if (user) {
        //user.message = "User already exists!!"
        response.statusCode = 409
        return response.send({"message": "User already exists!!")
    } else {
        User.register(new User({
                username: request.body.username,
                type: "Student"
            }),
            request.body.password,
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                passport.authenticate("local")(request, response, function() {
                    response.redirect("/");
                });
            });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: and if you are using react in the front end, then you can simply use notif from redux-notifications to throw a notification popup on the page.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using ejs and vueJS in the view. Quick question. Shouldn't there be a "reponse" in the else if (user) statement? Atm. this does not work

Comment: You can attach message and statusCode to response object. I have updated the above code.

Comment: I've tried that, but it gives me a timeout with a "request timeout" description.

Comment: Can you try debugging and consoling, and check if the user is getting retrieved from the database or not?

Comment: Yeah it does. So when I just enter "response.redirect('/') in the if (user) statement, then I'll get redirected if the username excists. So it should get the users correctly

Comment: Can you please console user in the else if block, and paste the result?

Comment: I can't do that. It just keeps loading and dont console anything due to the lack of response I guess

Comment: However, if I do response.send(user) it sends the correct user. So I'm sure it finds the correct one

Comment: So what happnds here, is the user is send as a response on a blank page as an object. Like this {"_id":"5fccc39daa34b1000439b88a","username":"xx","type":"Student"}

Comment: After the statement user.message = "User already exists!!", console.log(user), and paste the result here.

Comment: Still the same. It console logs a user object like before.

Comment: Try sending message object in response, like  the updated code above.